# WH40k: How do secret or obscure chapters (i.e. Grey Knights, Charcarodons) get techmarines?

Tags: warhammer-40k

In order for a Space Marine to become a techmarine, they must spend time training under the Mechanicum on Mars. This doesn't seem to be much of an issue for most Chapters, but what about those who don't have easy access to shipping lanes, or those who don't want their presence known?

One example is the Carcharodons Astra (or Space Sharks), who, according to Robbie MacNiven's novel [*Red Tithe*](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Carcharodons:_Red_Tithe_(Novel)), have effectively been exiled from the known galaxy, only appearing periodically to raid outlying colonies for supplies. According to sourcebooks, they have techmarines but they usually remain on their fleet due to their scarcity and importance, but you'd think that they would eventually need additional/replacement techmarines, even given the extended lifespan of a Space Marine.

Another example would be the Grey Knights. While they are practically neighbours of the Mechanicum, the Chapter is a secret to the average mortal, and even among other Chapters, they are thought of as a legend by most. So how do they get techmarines? They certainly have/need them, and according to [a Wiki](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Grey_Knights_Techmarine), they're trained on Mars like any other Marine. But do they arrive disguised in the livery of another chapter (or do the Grey Knights have a public-facing "front" Chapter) for such purposes? Or does the Mechanicum have special facilities to train them secretly?

If someone could point me to a novel our sourcebook to explain how these Chapters (the Grey Knights in particular) train their Techmarines, I'd love to see it. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, sadly i don't think there is such novel, but its safe to assume that techmarine-in-training is forbidden to mention his chapter - there is too much animosity between certain chapters (Dark Angels - Space Wolves, Ultramarines - Minotaurs, Marines Malevolent - Salamanders) that effective training would be difficult.

Comment: I do not think that there has ever been anything covering this topic either. I do not see them all training in obscurity however. Given that there are only a thousand* chapters I would think that at any given time only about a thousand new techs are being trained... it should be easy enough to keep them apart/ act professional. I might argue that anyone who was trying to stay "hidden" might just have a "copy" of the mechanicum in a knowledge machine and learn it the same way neophytes learn everything OR have a special section of mars they learn/train within while secluded... maybe they all do

Comment: Interesting input, @Yasskier. The novella Cybernetica involves several techmarines-in-training from several Legions (Iron Warriors, Ultramarines, Raven Guard, and Salamanders, I believe) at the onset of the Schism of Mars, and they seem to know each other's Legion. Of course, those were happier times, so it's definitely possible that, by the time the Grey Knights had been founded, this policy had been changed.

Comment: Its worth noting that the imperium of man doesn't actually know of every chapter of space marines and plenty of chapters have been wiped out or forgotten due to the logistical problems involved with the warp. its possible that the grey knights simply don the livery of a chapter that was gobbled up by nurgle at some point. alternatively since the inquisition technically answers to big E alone and can even recommission titans they might just say "TRAIN THIS MARINE, ASK NO QUESTIONS TELL NO ONE". if i where a lowly magos i would definitely do as told

Answer (score 8):

I don't have an answer for the Space Sharks, save perhaps that their tech marines are fairly venerable (especially if kept off the front line), and it's possible they have surges of tech marines - for example, they reappear for the Badab War, have a pretty intense resupply period, and then head back out again.

For the Grey Knights, note that they have their own dedicated Forge World. Deimos was hauled into orbit around Titan and then got obscured using the same mechanisms as Titan was. Given that, it seems likely they have their Tech Marines trained at the same Forge World that makes all their equipment, and with little/no direct interaction with Mars.

Comment: I do like your answer! Diemos is one of the two moons of Mars (The other beeing Phobos). And ye i also do remember that i read in a book that Diemos got pulled into Titans orbit. Hailing from Mars it most suredly had some Tech-Priests on it. Even if it didnt Malcador could have made a secret pact with the priesthood of Mars to send some Techpriests over so they can build exquisite stuff for the Gray Knights! Most of the stuff Gray Knights have is master crafted and ornate and not seen any other place... so Fomite +1 for remembering about Diemos.

Comment: I had also forgotten about Deimos. Excellent point, @Fomite!